# Dynamically updating the title, categories and size of highcharts-ng chart

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I need to be able to update the chart title and size when drilled down.

The drilldown function runs but the following code does nothing at all.

```
 // This gets called correctly, alert gets hit but does not change the title
 drilldown: function() {
                    alert('drilldown');

                    $scope.highchartsNG.title.text = 'New Title Test (drilldown)';
                }

    // This gets called at start and changes the title
    func: function (chart) {
        //setup some logic for the chart
        //alert('func');
        $scope.highchartsNG.title.text = 'New Title Test (func)';
    }
```

jsfiddle located at the following http://jsfiddle.net/vgmhgs0e/2/.  The actual drilldown does not work in this example but I have it working, I think that's because it doesn't have the code from this thread: [Highcharts-ng with drilldown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22195266/highcharts-ng-with-drilldown)

Comment: Any errors in the console? I can see `$watch`'es for size and title, to it should work. In the jsFiddle you are using `highchartsNG`, and in the code above `chartConfig` - maybe that's the problem?

Comment: The name can be anything I want.  That shouldn't be the issue, I noticed my jsfiddle was not correct, didn't save correctly and I have updated the link.  http://jsfiddle.net/vgmhgs0e/2/

Comment: I found something.  In the drilldown I added a $scope.$apply(); after I run the $scope.highchartsNG.title.text = "New Title Test (drilldown)';

That doesn't seem like a good programming practice but a good hack...