# Adding Multiple HighCharts on one screen Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, highcharts

I am new to HighCharts and I am trying add two Highcharts on the same p[age that are accessing the same data source but only taking certain pieces of for each graph. So for example the categories will remain the same however the series[] will change

```
function get_chart() {
    var options =   {
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            renderTo:'container'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Twitter Data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: []
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                    }
                }, point: {
                       events: {
                           click: function () {
                               alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.y);
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }

            },

        series: []

    };
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(json) {
        options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
        options.series[0] = json[1];
        options.series[1] = json[2];
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
}
get_chart();

var app = angular.module('charts', []);

app.directive('highchart', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch(attrs.chart, function () {

                if (!attrs.chart) return;

                var chart = scope.$eval(attrs.chart);

                angular.element(element).highcharts(chart);
            });

        }
    }
}]);

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.example_chart = get_chart();
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AngularJS + Highcarts </title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <section ng-app='charts'>
            <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
                <highchart chart='example_chart'></highchart>
            </div>
        </section>

        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/highChartStyle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/highChartAngular.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update** See this  [woking Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qzsmLAfKuTPo61pDU2hn?p=preview)

Because you are calling multiple highchart on same div. Id is unique in html and you can't define two div with same id.

pass div id in your function or call highcharts on classname like below:

```
get_chart(divParam)
```

and in chart object

```
chart: {
            type: 'column',
            renderTo:'divParam'
        }
```

Comment: lets say I wanted to duplicate the current example how would I implement that into the code?

Comment: If you want as it is series (mean same series at two place) call $.each(".classNameofDiv) , I will add a fiddle with example

Comment: let me know one more thing, Is your same call returning two dataset for two series? if yes, call the function in success of your call. I also created number of highchart graphs(including bar,column,line,pie,multiple y axis stacked etc) in my AngularJS app. if directive is not must, you can simply create charts

Comment: I am pretty much taking each data set and creating a single stacked chart, then the next 4-5 charts will be single bar charts representing the data individually.

Comment: How would I changed this to a grouped chart, and create a single stacked with all data, then 4-5 individual bar charts to break each data group set down.

Comment: you need drilldown chart, see this withAngularJS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32650447/highcharts-with-angularjs-drilled-down-does-not-work/32651657#32651657 and see my fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/uqpgnf8y/5/